# iPad / iPhone Sync (WLAN or Inet)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, synchronization

I have actually one app with a SQLite DB and i port this at the moment to the ipad.

My idea is a sync between iPad and iPhone for one table... But the Problem is "Person A" edit/change, create or delete a data record on iphone and "Person B" make the same or delete the edited record from Person A on the same time. Has anybody a idea for this? Or a nice lib for this?

Answer (score 0):

The [Bump API](http://bu.mp/api.html) can probably do what you're looking for.